# Conjoint Analysis - How they do it?

Tags: spss, conjoint-analysis

[image]

Theoretically what I know that, for doing Conjoint Analysis I have to make a list of all the possible products with five different features utilizing all the combination of different levels (see figure). Here the number is (3X3X3X3X3=243). Then I have to ask the respondent to rank among the listed possible products in decreasing order of preference. I feel it is impractical. But I have heard that Conjoint Analysis has a vital role in any company because conjoint analysis is performed to determine what combination of features is most influential on respondent choice or purchase decision making. But how they do it? Please help me by explaining in details.

Comment: I added tag `spss` because by the looks of your other question you work with it.

Comment: Conjoint analysis in SPSS is classic full-profile conjoint analysis. Mathematically it is main-effects ANOVA which you can be performed on the level of each individual or the sample of individuals. It uses orthogonal design. By a program creating cards (profiles) - See Data - Orthogonal design it is possible to create less cards than the exhaustive 3X3X3X3X3=243 combinations. In this particular case, as few as 16 cards with special combinations can suffice, and be orthogonal main-effect design: all pairwise Cramer's V between the 5 factors are 0.

Comment: Conjoint analysis is used primarily in deciding pricing and product features, for example when you are launching a new product. Try an online tool, such as [Conjoint.ly](https://conjoint.ly) that will guide you through the steps of conjoint analysis.